# Error occur while connecting Socket.io in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm Facing an issue while connection the socket in react js App
[image]

this is my app.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import {socket} from './socket/socket'

function App() {
  const [, setIsConnected] = useState(socket.connected);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    function onConnect() {
      setIsConnected(true);
    }

    function onDisconnect() {
      setIsConnected(false);
    }
    socket.on('connect', onConnect);
    socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);

    return () => {
      socket.off('connect', onConnect);
      socket.off('disconnect', onDisconnect);
    };
  }, []);
  const clickHandle = () => {
    socket.emit("message", value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={clickHandle}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my socket.js file

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const socket = io("wss://viewer.soar3d.io:6000/")
```

Here I've created `socket.js` file for connection and I used that connection in `app.js`. when i refresh the page I'm facing below issue, please help me to fix the issue